# exact way to load listbox images

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am developing a windows phone app where I am collecting images from media library and adding each item to listbox.Here is my code....

```
public MainPage()
{
InitializeComponent();
getImages();

}
public void getImages()
{
try
{
    MediaLibrary mediaLibrary = new MediaLibrary();
    var pictures = mediaLibrary.Pictures;
    foreach (var picture in pictures)
    {
        BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
        image.SetSource(picture.GetImage());//out of memory exception
        img mediaImage = new img();
        mediaImage.Imgs = image;
        imageList.Items.Add(mediaImage);
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{

}
```

}

```
public class img
{
public img()
{ }
public BitmapImage Imgs { get; set; }
}
```

in Xaml...

```
<ScrollViewer Name="sc" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Margin="0,422,0,43">
    <ListBox Name="imageList" SelectionChanged="imageList_SelectionChanged_1" Height="126">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate >
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></StackPanel>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate >
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Margin="10" Name="image1" Source="{Binding Imgs}" Height="150" Width="150"></Image>
                    </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</ScrollViewer>
```

When I am loading this list box I am getting a Out of memory exception in Picture.GetImage()
I have written in code.Please tell me how to release memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Win32 tends to throw out of memory exceptions for invalid image files. Not sure if this is still true for WP7.

So let's assume it's not the case - is the exception thrown only for a single, specific image? Or is thrown when you already have loaded some images, making it a real "out of memory" situation?

If the latter: You do NOT want to load all images into a list box - a user could have thousands of pictures. You probably want to load thumbnails instead - in this case you call the GetThumbnail method. You should also limit the number of loaded thumbnails and/or use a (re)virtualizing, lazy-loading ListBox and/or watch the available RAM to stop loading further thumbnails.